# Algorithm for graphing heap data from server memory

Tags: node.js, graph, statistics, smoothing, graphing

Right now I am collecting memory information on a node.js server every 100 seconds. I want do display the memory usage info as a graph on the front end.

```
const mem = {
  heapTotals: [],
  heapUseds: [],
  maxHeapTotal: 0,
  maxHeapUsed: 0
};

setInterval(function () {

  const m = process.memoryUsage();
  mem.heapTotals.push(m.heapTotal);
  mem.heapUseds.push(m.heapUsed);

  if (m.heapTotal > maxMem.maxHeapTotal) {
    mem.maxHeapTotal = m.heapTotal;
  }
  if (m.heapUsed > maxMem.maxHeapUsed) {
    mem.maxHeapUsed = m.heapUsed;
  }

}, 100000);
```

We aren't storing it in a db, or anything, just in memory. Of course, we keep pushing to that array every 100 seconds, it's going to start growing over time if our server is live for awhile.

I am looking for a fun algorithm I can use every 100 seconds, to refine the array, so that it has no more than say 2000 entries.

*I need a way to go through the existing array, remove past items, but average them with their peers, so that the graph is somewhat smooth.*

Say I have this:

```
[3,3,5,5,6,7,9,2,3,5,3,6,4,8,8,4,4,5]  (18 items)
```

I would reduce it by taking every 3rd item, and averaging it and the two before it, so it would be:

```
[(3+3+5)/3,(5+6+7)/3,(9+2+3)/3,(5+3+6)/3,(4+8+8)/3,(4+4+5)/3]
```

Something like that. However that is not really a complete algorithm. Does anyone know of the right/best way to do this so that the graph is accurate but doesn't keep growing beyond 2000 array entries etc?

Comment: Are there any timestamps? Do you want the averages to be uniform over a given period? Does it need to be within a single array, or would you prefer multiple arrays that represent different time resolutions?

Comment: I could add a timestamp - really only need one resolution though

Comment: the resolution can decrease over time, not a big deal..might be nice to have a long-term resolution and then a short term resolution that's only the last 5 days or something

Comment: If something thinks I should be collective memory usage more frequently than every 100 seconds, lmk, but that seems frequent enough. Btw, every 100 seconds, is about 900x per day.